# Pandas DatetimeIndex indexing dtype: datetime64 vs Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

Indexing a pandas DatetimeIndex (with dtype numpy datetime64[ns]) returns either:

- another DatetimeIndex for multiple indices
- a pandas Timestamp for single index

The confusing part is that Timestamps do not equal np.datetime64, so that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a_datetimeindex = pd.date_range('1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', freq = 'D')
print np.in1d(a_datetimeindex[0], a_datetimeindex)
```

Returns false. But:

```
print np.in1d(a_datetimeindex[0:1], a_datetimeindex)
print np.in1d(np.datetime64(a_datetimeindex[0]), a_datetimeindex)
```

Returns the right results.

I guess that is because np.datetime64[ns] has accuracy to the nanosecond, but the Timestamp is truncated?

My question is, is there a way to create the DatetimeIndex so that it always indexes to the same (or comparable) data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using numpy functions to manipulate pandas types. They are not always compatible.

The function `np.in1d` first converts its both arguments to ndarrays. A `DatetimeIndex` has a built-in conversion and an array of dtype `np.datetime64` is returned (it's `DatetimIndex.values`). But a `Timestamp` doesn't have such a facility and it's not converted.

Instead, you can use for example a python keyword `in` (the most natural way):

```
a_datetimeindex[0] in a_datetimeindex
```

or an `Index.isin` method for a collection of elements

```
a_datetimeindex.isin(a_list_or_index)
```

If you want to use `np.in1d`, explicitly convert both arguments to numpy types. Or call it on the underlying numpy arrays:

```
np.in1d(a_datetimeindex.values[0], a_datetimeindex.values)
```

Alternatively, it's probably safe to use `np.in1d` with two collections of the same type:

```
np.in1d(a_datetimeindex, another_datetimeindex)
```

or even

```
np.in1d(a_datetimeindex[[0]], a_datetimeindex)
```